# Query to update subscriber status to a list in salesforce marketing cloud

Tags: sql, salesforce

I have a data extension that I will be populating my subscriber information into (I have to do this due to my API set up). However, I want this information to be pasted to my publication list in salesforce. If people unsubscribe, a field in my data extension called 'Subscribed' will be updated to 'False' (and vica-versa). I want to set up a query to run everday that scans this data extension and updates all the false records to unsubscibed in my publication list. I built the query below, but I am getting an error that say

> "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INNER'."

```
SELECT b.EMAIL_ADDRESS, 'Unsubscribed' AS Status
FROM Welcome b
WHERE b.Subscribed = 'False'
AND Date_Changed >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE())
INNER JOIN _ListSubscribers a
ON a.EmailAddress = b.EMAIL_ADDRESS
WHERE a.ListID = '112'
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Where` clause always goes after `joins`

```
SELECT b.EMAIL_ADDRESS, 'Unsubscribed' AS Status
FROM Welcome b
INNER JOIN _ListSubscribers a ON a.EmailAddress = b.EMAIL_ADDRESS
WHERE b.Subscribed = 'False' and 
      a.ListID = '112' and
      b.Date_Changed >= DATEADD(day, -1, GETDATE());
```